# Calculus application

Tags: calculus

The value of a certain car $t$ years after it is purchased is given by $$V(t)=40,000(\frac{9}{10})^{1.6t}$$
By what percent is the population decreasing each year?  Round to the nearest tenth of a percent. Notice that the exponent in the function above is $1.5t$, not $t$.

What does it mean by population decrease? Is this the derivative of the given model? Also, I don't understand $1.5t$ when it is $1.6t$ in the above function. Is this problem misleading? Please help.

Comment: 1.5 vs 1.6 looks like a typo in the problem.

Comment: How about the population decrease for each year? What is meant by this question?

Comment: This is probably "cut and paste" run amok...

Comment: What is the relation between *population* and *value of a certain car t years after it is purchased* ? It could be good you reset the words of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the "population" is the value of the function, though it seems a strange choice of words to me.  You are expected to tabluate the value for $t=0,1,2,\dots $ and find the percentage decrease from $t=0$ to $t=1$, etc.  You should find the percentage decrease to be constant in this model.